# How to force EditText to accept system readings and NEVER user inputs?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want my `edittext` never to accept user inputs, though, it should accept the `GPS` readings only when they are ready as in the picture below. I tried to utilize`android:editable="false"`, but it is deprecated to `inputtype`.

Is there anyway to achieve this.

Pic:
[image]

Comment: why are you using an EditText for this? why not use a TextView?

Comment: @panini because before designing my app i checked some other app's feature that are designed for almost the same purpose, and they were using edittext. an example for that, an app that is using GPS signal, they created a textview as a label and the reading was displayed in an edittext.

Comment: have you tried using android:focusable="false" ?

Comment: How can you tell they are using `EditText` for readings if its not editable?

Comment: you can do it programatically **yourEditText.setEnabled(false);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via your component xml file

```
<EditText>
            android:clickable="false" 
            android:focusable="false" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"

</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this dynamically, do the below.

```
    final EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtControl);

    text.setEnabled(false);
    text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```